# Запись строки в файл при условии обнаружения ключевого слова в выводе программы

Tags: bash, консоль

Условная программа при выполнении выводит некоторый текст, если в тексте обнаруживается  `done` то скрипт должен записать условную строку `str` в файл `detect.txt`

```
программа | grep done echo 'str' >> detect.txt
```

Мой пример с ошибкой, укажите как правильно запускать скрипт?

Comment: `программа | grep -q done && echo 'str' >> detect.txt` — однократная запись: с опцией `-q` программа *grep* сразу же завершит работу (с нулевым кодом возврата) при появлении в её *stdin* строки, содержащей слово `done`

Comment: @alexanderbarakin оформите в виде ответа решение.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ программа | grep -q done && echo 'str' >> detect.txt
```

будет произведена однократная запись слова `str` в указанный файл: с опцией `-q` программа *grep* сразу же завершит работу (с нулевым кодом возврата) при появлении в её *stdin* строки, содержащей слово `done`.

---

но будьте осторожны: ваша `программа` должна уметь корректно обрабатывать ситуацию, когда её *stdout* (перенаправляемый оболочкой на *stdin* программы *grep*) будет внезапно закрыт (и процесс получит [сигнал *pipe*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGPIPE)).